# Microsoft Skype for Business Integration in Android app

Tags: skype-for-business

Hi Everyone ,
              I am developing android in which need Microsoft Skype for Business Integration. so that user can have feature of Video call and Chat etc. I am using this [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples).
when i am running GuestMeetingJoin sample app getting this error :

05-04 12:03:15.433 32446-32446/com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo-1/libacomo.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1636): could not load library "libsqlcipher.so" needed by "libacomo.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:746): library "libsqlcipher.so" not found
05-04 12:03:15.463 32446-32446/com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo/com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load native library
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load native library
                                                                                      at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.LoadNativeLibrary(Application.java:129)
                                                                                      at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.initialize(Application.java:71)
                                                                                      at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.getInstance(Application.java:143)
                                                                                      at com.microsoft.office.sfb.sfbdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-04 12:03:15.893 553-602/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
05-04 12:03:25.823 10400-10400/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.common.permission.PermissionUtils$1', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsModuleInitializer.initializeModuleV0

Answer (score 0):

Please keep noted that [Skype for Business (SfB)](https://products.office.com/en/skype-for-business/online-meetings) [former known as Lync] isn´t the same as [Skype for Consumer (SfC)](https://www.skype.com/en/).

**Skype for consumer (SfC):**

Is mostly used by consumer and do not require to install any environment.

**Skype for Business (SfB):**

Is used by companies and it required to setup an dedicated environment (in the cloud or in the own datacenter). With SfB it is possible to have [a federation between SfC and SfB so that users are able to chat and perform calls with each other](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn705313.aspx). So if you wish to include SfB you can use UCWA or UCMA.

For UCWA here are some starting points:

- [Unified Communications Web API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0)
- [Developing UCWA applications for Skype for Business Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline)
- [UCWA 2.0 general reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/ucwa2_0generalreference)

So do no get confused here...